# Ensuring a value is retrieved only once

Tags: go, concurrency, synchronization

I'm developing a Go package to access a web service (via HTTP). Every time I retrieve a page of data from that service, I also get the total of pages available. The only way to get this total is by getting one of the pages (usually the first one). However, requests to this service take time and I need to do the following:

When the `GetPage` method is called on a `Client` and the page is retrieved for the first time, the retrieved total should be stored somewhere in that client. When the `Total` method is called and the total hasn't yet been retrieved, the first page should be fetched and the total returned. If the total was retrieved before, either by a call to `GetPage` or `Total`, it should be returned immediately, without any HTTP requests at all. This needs to be safe for use by multiple goroutines. My idea is something along the lines of `sync.Once` but with the function passed to `Do` returning a value, which is then cached and automatically returned whenever `Do` is called.

I remember seeing something like this before, but I can't find it now even though I tried. Searching for `sync.Once` with value and similar terms didn't yield any useful results. I know I could probably do that with a mutex and a lot of locking, but mutexes and a lot of locking don't seem to be the recommended way to do stuff in go.

Comment: If you don't think mutexes are the way to do things in go, you should [have a look at the source of `sync.Once`](https://golang.org/src/sync/once.go?s=260:305#L2).

Comment: `sync.Once` is how you typically ensure something is only done once. What problem did you have actually using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### General "init-once" solution

In the general / usual case, the easiest solution to only init once, only when it's actually needed is to use [`sync.Once`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Once) and its [`Once.Do()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Once.Do) method.

You don't actually need to return any value from the function passed to `Once.Do()`, because you can store values to e.g. global variables in that function.

See this simple example:

```
var (
    total         int
    calcTotalOnce sync.Once
)

func GetTotal() int {
    // Init / calc total once:
    calcTotalOnce.Do(func() {
        fmt.Println("Fetching total...")
        // Do some heavy work, make HTTP calls, whatever you want:
        total++ // This will set total to 1 (once and for all)
    })

    // Here you can safely use total:
    return total
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(GetTotal())
    fmt.Println(GetTotal())
}
```

Output of the above (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hxZE8YskmDV)):

```
Fetching total...
1
1
```

Some notes:

- You can achieve the same using a mutex or `sync.Once`, but the latter is actually faster than using a mutex.
- If `GetTotal()` has been called before, subsequent calls to `GetTotal()` will not do anything but return the previously calculated value, this is what `Once.Do()` does / ensures. `sync.Once` "tracks" if its `Do()` method has been called before, and if so, the passed function value will not be called anymore.
- `sync.Once` provides all the needs for this solution to be safe for concurrent use from multiple goroutines, given that you don't modify or access the `total` variable directly from anywhere else.

### Solution to your "unusal" case

The general case assumes the `total` is only accessed via the `GetTotal()` function.

In your case this does not hold: you want to access it via the `GetTotal()` function **and** you want to set it after a `GetPage()` call (if it has not yet been set).

We may solve this with `sync.Once` too. We would need the above `GetTotal()` function; and when a `GetPage()` call is performed, it may use the same `calcTotalOnce` to attempt to set its value from the received page.

It could look something like this:

```
var (
    total         int
    calcTotalOnce sync.Once
)

func GetTotal() int {
    calcTotalOnce.Do(func() {
        // total is not yet initialized: get page and store total number
        page := getPageImpl()
        total = page.Total
    })

    // Here you can safely use total:
    return total
}

type Page struct {
    Total int
}

func GetPage() *Page {
    page := getPageImpl()

    calcTotalOnce.Do(func() {
        // total is not yet initialized, store the value we have:
        total = page.Total
    })

    return page
}

func getPageImpl() *Page {
    // Do HTTP call or whatever
    page := &Page{}
    // Set page.Total from the response body
    return page
}
```

How does this work? We create and use a single `sync.Once` in the variable `calcTotalOnce`. This ensures that its `Do()` method may only call the function passed to it *once*, no matter where / how this `Do()` method is called.

If someone calls the `GetTotal()` function first, then the function literal inside it will run, which calls `getPageImpl()` to fetch the page and initialize the `total` variable from the `Page.Total` field.

If `GetPage()` function would be called first, that will also call `calcTotalOnce.Do()` which simply sets the `Page.Total` value to the `total` variable.

Whichever route is walked first, that will alter the internal state of `calcTotalOnce`, which will remember the `total` calculation has already been run, and further calls to `calcTotalOnce.Do()` will never call the function value passed to it.

### Or just use "eager" initialization

Also note that if it is likely that this total number have to be fetched during the lifetime of your program, it might not worth the above complexity, as you may just as easily initialize the variable once, when it's created.

```
var Total = getPageImpl().Total
```

Or if the initialization is a little more complex (e.g. needs error handling), use a package `init()` function:

```
var Total int

func init() {
    page := getPageImpl()
    // Other logic, e.g. error handling
    Total = page.Total
}
```

Comment: How to check if the value has already been fetched, then? I know I can use a bool, but is that safe? What if one goroutine reads from that bool while another one writes to it?

Comment: You don't need to check. That check is done by `Once.Do()`. If your function is called, it has not yet been set.

Comment: total may have already been set by an earlier call to GetPage though and in that case GetTotal shouldn't do anything. I don't think sync.Once is the solution here. Just use a mutex.

Comment: @Peter A mutex is slower than using `sync.Once`. And the result is the same.

Comment: @Peter If `GetPage()` has been called before, the example above will not do anything but return the previously calculated value. That's what `Once.Do()` does / ensures.

Comment: @icza, you may want to add your implementation of GetPage then. I don't see GetPage invoking the Once.

Comment: @Peter You're right, the answer wasn't covering the asker's need entirely. Added explicit solution / explanation to the asker's specific case.

Comment: I only just now realized that you can pass different functions to Do. I always assumed you have to pass the same function at every call site. Makes sense now, thanks.